# pandas: create a long/tidy DataFrame from dictionary when values are sets or lists of variable length

Tags: python, pandas, unnest

Simple dictionary:

```
d = {'a': set([1,2,3]), 'b': set([3, 4])}
```

(the sets may be turned into lists if it matters)

How do I convert it into a long/tidy `DataFrame` in which each column is a variable and every observation is a row, i.e.:

```
  letter  value
0      a      1
1      a      2
2      a      3
3      b      3
4      b      4
```

The following works, but it's a bit cumbersome:

```
id = 0
tidy_d = {}
for l, vs in d.items():
    for v in vs:
        tidy_d[id] = {'letter': l, 'value': v}
        id += 1
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tidy_d, orient = 'index')
```

Is there any `pandas` magic to do this? Something like:

```
pd.DataFrame([d]).T.reset_index(level=0).unnest()
```

where `unnest` obviously doesn't exist and comes from R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comprehension with `itertools.chain` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain

keys, values = map(chain.from_iterable, zip(*((k*len(v), v) for k, v in d.items())))

df = pd.DataFrame({'letter': list(keys), 'value': list(values)})

print(df)

  letter  value
0      a      1
1      a      2
2      a      3
3      b      3
4      b      4
```

This can be rewritten in a more readable fashion:

```
zipper = zip(*((k*len(v), v) for k, v in d.items()))
values = map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, zipper))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(values), columns=['letter', 'value'])
```

Comment: notice there's an issue if the keys in `d` are int, i.e. `d = {0: set([1,2,3]), 1: set([3, 4])}`, in which case it will throw a TypeError.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni, Good point. Of course, OP has specified strings in the input dictionary, but your point should be noted for adapting to other problems.

Comment: Got bitten by int keys - `keys, values = map(chain.from_iterable, zip(*(([k]*len(v), v) for k, v in d.items())))` for adapting to other problems

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter' : np.repeat(list(d.keys()), [len(v) for k, v in d.items()]),
    'value' : list(chain.from_iterable(d.values())), 
})
print (df)
  letter  value
0      a      1
1      a      2
2      a      3
3      b      3
4      b      4
```

Comment: You can use `list(d)` here. Also `list(map(len, d.values()))` [or, at least iterate `values` here rather than `items`].

Answer (score 2):

A tad more "pandaic", inspired by [this](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas/) post:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient = 'index') \
  .rename_axis('letter').reset_index() \
  .melt(id_vars = ['letter'], value_name = 'value') \
  .drop('variable', axis = 1) \
  .dropna()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what melt does?

Comment: Think of a "wide" data table which melts into a "long" one. Columns "week1", "week2", "week3" melt into a single column named "week" having values "1", "2" and "3", and an additional column "value" is added. The docs may explain it better: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 1):

Some timings of [melt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56642967/281545) and slightly modified [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52626792/281545) answers:

```
import random
import timeit
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)

dict_size = 1000000
randoms = [random.randint(0, 100) for __ in range(10000)]
max_list_size = 1000
d = {k: random.sample(randoms, random.randint(1, max_list_size)) for k in
     range(dict_size)}

def chain_():
    keys, values = map(chain.from_iterable,
                       zip(*(([k] * len(v), v) for k, v in d.items())))
    pd.DataFrame({'letter': list(keys), 'value': list(values)})

def melt_():
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index'
        ).rename_axis('letter').reset_index(
        ).melt(id_vars=['letter'], value_name='value'
        ).drop('variable', axis=1).dropna()

setup ="""from __main__ import chain_, melt_"""
repeat = 3
numbers = 10
def timer(statement, _setup=''):
  print(min(
    timeit.Timer(statement, setup=_setup or setup).repeat(repeat, numbers)))

print('timing')
timer('chain_()')
timer('melt_()')
```

Seems melt is faster for max_list_size 100:

```
1.0.3
timing
246.71311019999996
204.33705529999997
```

and slower for max_list_size 1000:

```
2675.8446872
4565.838648400002
```

probably because of assigning the memory for a much bigger df than needed

A variation of chain answer:

```
def chain_2():
    keys, values = map(chain.from_iterable,
                       zip(*((itertools.repeat(k, len(v)), v) for k, v in d.items())))
    pd.DataFrame({'letter': list(keys), 'value': list(values)})
```

doesn't seem to be any faster

(python 3.7.6)

Answer (score 0):

Just another one,

```
from collections import defaultdict
e = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in d.items():
    e["letter"] += [key] * len(val)
    e["value"] += list(val)
df = pd.DataFrame(e)
```